# When is a Koszul algebra derived equivalent to its dual

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, koszul-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional Koszul algebra of finite global dimension.

> Question: When is $A$ derived equivalent to its Koszul dual algebra?

I wonder whether there is an exact condition to describe when this happens.

For example when $A$ is the linear oriented Dynkin type $A_n$ path algebra, $A$ is derived equivalent to its Koszul dual.

When $A$ is the Auslander algebra of $K[x]/(x^4)$, $A$ is not derived equivalent to its Koszul dual (they have non-isomorphic centers).